# Get UserID from ASP.Net Login control LoggedIn event

Tags: asp.net, authentication, userid

In ASP.Net, I am trying to get the UserId (i.e., the user GUID) of the user that just logged on, in the LoggedIn event of the Login control. That is, I want to grab the UserId before the user is moved to to the next page. This is the code I am using:

```
Protected Sub Login1_LoggedIn(ByVal sender As Object, _
  ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Login1.LoggedIn

    Dim UserId As String
    UserId = Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString()

End Sub
```

However, I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. This same code works well when I use it in subsequent pages, when a logged in user is accessing these pages.

Comment: Shouldn't that be Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString()?

Comment: @pmarflee - This is VB.NET.  The () after GetUser is optional. (As is the () after ToString)!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/Scottgu/) has the answer to this problem, as explained in [this blog post](http://forums.asp.net/t/982749.aspx) on the ASP.NET Forum:

> The LoggedIn event fires immediately
>   after the user is logged in with the
>   login control -- but not before the
>   next request to the site.  As such,
>   the User object isn't filled out yet.

If you change your code to something like:

```
Dim UserId As String
UserID = Membership.GetUser(Login1.UserName).ProviderUserKey.ToString()
```

It should work fine.  Calling `Membership.GetUser` without passing the Username as a parameter will expect to grab the "current" logged in user.  Of course, this fails for the above reasons as the `User` object is not yet populated.  By passing the `Login` control's `UserName` property as a parameter to the `GetUser()` method, you explicitly force the `Membership.GetUser` method to retrieve the user as specified by name from the user store (i.e. database).  This ensures that the `Membership.GetUser` method returns a valid `MembershipUser` object which allows you to access the `ProviderUserKey` property.

Comment: @PropositionJoe: it this answer was the solution to your problem, you should mark it as accepted! Thanks!