# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false in Login control LoggedIn event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I am getting mad regarding why would HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated return false in LoggedIn event in Login control?

I type the correct username and password and hence I am in loggedin event but yet the IsAuthenticated is false!

Comment: How is your iis setup? How about the web.config? Are you using FormsAuthentication? How about some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the page hasn't been posted back since the user logged in.  The entire User object is not filled out yet, this is a known behavior.

See this very informative blog post:

http://forums.asp.net/t/982749.aspx

Also credit for the above link goes to this related SO QA:
[Get UserID from ASP.Net Login control LoggedIn event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599698/get-userid-from-asp-net-login-control-loggedin-event)

Answer (score 2):

`Application_AuthenticateRequest` happens very early staging of the page life cycle.

If you are in `LoggedIn` event, you can assume that the user is already authenticated.

If you want a logged-in user's username, you can get it like this -

```
protected void LoginUser_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var usernameTextBox = (TextBox)LoginUser.FindControl("UserName");
    string username = usernameTextBox.Text;

    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(username);
    Guid userId = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
}
```