# Best way to trigger a function once after a user is authenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a procedure that has to be run once when a user logs into my asp.net website. The closest event that i could find is the LoggedIn event on my login control and the Session_Start from Global.asax, however i cannot use these as they are not able to find the UserId of the currently logged in user yet.

So, what is the best way to run a procedure once after a user is authenticated?

Code that i use to call procedure (maby it can be altered to not use userid here yet ?)

```
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand comm;

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LoginProject"].ConnectionString;
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        string UserId = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();
        comm = new SqlCommand("TrackLoggedInUser", conn);
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
        comm.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = UserId;
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserLoginId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the built-in auth, AD, or some other method?

Comment: Yes, build in Login control with the Microsoft asp.net Default database behind it.

Comment: If you're using the Forms auth, you can check if the user is authenticated and take action from there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/874sbx60(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Hmm this seems interesting, Could you give me an example? Or give me some instructions on how to work with this with my problem. Maby make it answer so i can validate it? note that i am indeed using forms auth

Comment: Note that `AddWithValue()` is not expecting `SqlDbType` but value. Anyway, can't you change stored procedure to use username instead of id?

Comment: And how would i do this? is there something similar to Membership.getuser that i can fetch the username with? Or do i have to edit my database?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1599841/551322) helps.

Comment: Wow, that did in fact work. All i had to do is change string UserId = Membership.GetUser(login1.Username).ProviderUserKey.ToString(); 

Maby you can make an answer out of that and ill validate it for other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1599841/551322).

All you have to do is provide username to `GetUser()` as in

```
Membership.GetUser(login1.Username).ProviderUserKey.ToString()
```